# Is it possible that each areas on MVC2 run on separate IIS website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Lets say I want my Admin (area) to run on HTTPS
and the default site runs on HTTP.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to force SSL in MVC 2.0](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-ssl-with-aspnet-mvc-2.html)

```
public AccountController: Controller{
   [RequireHttps(Order=1), Authorize(Roles="Users",Order=2)]
   public ActionResult Login(){
      // Add login logic
      return View();
    } 
}
```

The only other thing you will need to do is setup your SSL cert in IIS, but don't require it if you only want to use it in certain areas/controllers/functions.